# Salesforce SmartStore app becoming offline to online

Tags: api, android

I am developing a SmartStore android app. What I need to do is when my device goes from offline (not connected to internet) to online (connected to internet) then the data which I stored offline should get uploaded to salesforce automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can check in your android application if a device is connected to internet or not :-

```
   // Call android connectivity services. Require "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
   ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = connectManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   // return true if internet available
   return currentNetworkInfo != null && currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()
```

and to check for connection automatically as device connection status change you can register a listener by using `BroadcastReciever`

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

   NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
   //You can paste the above code for network info here
   // or execute some method as you get some desired network state
   }
};


// Register action as
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(); // init
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION); // add action
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter); // register
```